# Can an Antipaladin combine Touch of Corruption and a held touch spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class, antipaladin

In pathfinder, can an antipaladin deliver a held touch spell (e.g. inflict moderate wounds) and touch of corruption at the same time? I have quoted items that I feel are relevant.

> From the Player's Guide: Holding the Charge: If you don't discharge the spell in the round when you cast the spell, you can hold the charge indefinitely. You can continue to make touch attacks round after round. **If you touch anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges**. If you cast another spell, the touch spell dissipates. You can touch one friend as a standard action or up to six friends as a full round action. Alternatively, you can make a normal unarmed attack (or an attack with a natural weapon) while holding the charge. In this case, you aren't considered armed and you provoke attacks of opportunity as normal for attack. If your unarmed attack or natural weapon doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity, neither does this attack. If the attack hits, you deal normal damage for your unarmed attack or natural weapon and the spell discharges. If the attack misses, you are still holding the charge. (Emphasis mine)

Then

> From the Advanced Player's Guide: Touch of Corruption (Su) - Beginning at 2nd level, an antipaladin surrounds his hand with a fiendish flame, causing terrible wounds to open on those he touches. ... As a touch attack an antipaladin can cause 1d6 points of damage for every two antipaladin levels he possesses. Using this ability is a standard action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

My thought is that since touch of corruption is a supernatural ability, it doesn't count for the limit of one held spell at any given time. So before combat, an antipaladin would cast inflict moderate wounds and hold the spell. Then, he would attempt a touch of corruption. Assuming the attack hits, it causes the touch of corruption effects in addition to the discharged inflict wounds. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, this will work, as a 2-stage attack.

Cast the Inflict spell (or whatever your touch spell would be) first, and hold the charge, as per your first quote.

On your next action, use Touch of Corruption as normal. When (if) you hit with Touch of Corruption, whatever you have touched immediately fulfills the trigger clause for "holding a charge", and the Inflict spell is delivered.

It won't work in the reverse order, as Touch of Corruption can't be "held".

Answer (score 1):

There is no official clarification if this should be possible or not, so it will be subject to table variation, but lets take some things into consideration:

I believe that summoning the flames and touching a creature are part of said **Standard Action** of Touch of Corruption, unless i am mistaken. That ability is supposedly similar to **Lay on Hands** and should behave similarly. So you cannot "hold" touch of corruption, as the ability doesn't actually say you can do that (in pathfinder, that means you can't do it unless said otherwise), the same way you cannot hold a lay on hands, so you must use a Standard Action to call the flames and then touch a target.

> You can touch one friend as a standard action

So how exactly will you deliver a touch attack, a **Standard Action** and use Touch of Corruption, another **Standard Action**, on the same round? Not possible unless you somehow can make more than **one standard action per round**.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't necessarily implying that one would hold Touch of Corruption, but rather use the standard action for ToC, and then the touch spell would simply discharge when you touched them (which the rules indicate would happen even if you touched something accidentally). I suppose the question hinges upon whether or not one MUST use a standard action to discharge a held touch spell.

Comment: The answer to that isnt difficult: No. One way of discharging is a standard action to touch, but any kind of touch attack should discharge it. Even an attack of opportunity as an unarmed strike can deliver the charge.